# SQL join without losing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables with the same schema of userID, category, count.  I need a query to sum the count of each userID/category pair.  Sometimes a pair will exist in one table and not the other.  I'm having trouble doing a join without losing the rows where a userID/category pair only exists in 1 table.  This is what I'm trying (without success):

```
select a.user, a.category, count=a.count+b.count
from #temp1 a join #temp2 b
on a.user = b.user and a.category = b.category
```

Example:

Input:

```
user    category    count
id1     catB        3
id2     catG        9
id3     catW        17

user    category    count
id1     catB        1
id2     catM        5
id3     catW        13
```

Desired Output:

```
user    category    count
id1     catB        4
id2     catG        9
id2     catM        5
id3     catW        30
```

Update: "count" is not the actual column name.  I just used it for the sake of this example,  and I forgot it's a reserved word.

Comment: Why ID2 is not summed? it is in both tables.

Comment: @SNash, the categories differ. You may want to re-read the requirements for summation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use a full outer join so you don't drop rows present in one table and not the other
2. Coalesce counts prior to addition, because 0 + NULL = NULL

Also, because `COUNT` is a reserved word, I would recommend escaping it.

So, using all of these guidelines, your query becomes:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.user, b.user) AS user, 
       COALESCE(a.category, b.category) AS category, 
       COALESCE(a.[count],0) + COALESCE(b.[count],0) AS [count]
FROM #temp1 AS a 
FULL OUTER JOIN #temp2 AS b
             ON a.user = b.user AND 
                a.category = b.category
```

Comment: Perfect!  I was not aware of COALESCE, this is exactly what I needed.  I also believe "AS [count]" is extraneous since you have "[count] =" at the beginning of that line.

Comment: @JCB, I meant to remove the ```[count] =``` part, which I have done in the last edit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this is with a full outer join:

```
select coalesce(a.user, b.user) as user,
       coalesce(a.category, b.category) as category,
       coalesce(a.count, 0) + coalesce(b.count, 0) as "count"
from #temp1 a full outer join
     #temp2 b
     on a.user = b.user and
         a.category = b.category;
```

When using `full outer join`, you have to be careful because the key fields can be `NULL` when there is a match in only one table.  As a result, the `select` tends to have a lot of `coalesce()`s (or similar constructs).

Another way is using a `union all` query with aggregation:

```
select "user", category, SUM(count) as "count"
from ((select "user", category, "count"
       from #temp1
      ) union all
      (select "user", category, "count"
       from #temp2
      )
     ) t
group by "user", category
```